# In hadoop streaming, can I write files to the local disc in the reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, reducers

In hadoop streaming, can I write files to the local disc in the reducer?

For example, in the reducer by C++, if I code

```
ofstream fout(***);
fout << "asdf";
```

Does this make sense? And where will the file created by `fout` be?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop streaming will be using the Hadoop `OutputFormatters` such as `TextOutputFormat`. Thus, one way to get specific output behavior, other than those provided by the built-in formats would be to write a custom output format, and override the `getRecordWriter(TaskAttemptContext context)` method.

I'm not sure if writing to the local disk directly from the reduce would work, it might be fine. You would need to give it a go. The main problem with this is that in a cluster you don't know which nodes the reducers will be running on and you loose a lot of the reliability that HDFS provides.

Answer (score 0):

reducer is not able to write directly to local fs if fs.default is not file:/// in hdfs-site.xml. By default reducer will store the output in that filesystem which is provided in hdfs-site.xml.